# How to just open an iframe with fancybox effect with onclick event

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, onclick, fancybox

I am trying to pen an iframe with fancybox effect, and i need to use onclick event, so i try with this code, the iframe is opened with fancybox effect but without the onclick event...

```
<div class="addelement"><li>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="addelements.php" onclick="showelementbox(\''+data.msg+'\');
parent.scrollTo(00, 00);"></a></li>
</div>
```

Or is it possible to make something like this?

```
<div class="addelement">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$FANCYBOX EVENT TO OPEN THE IFRAME();showelementbox(\''+data.msg+'\');
parent.scrollTo(00, 00);"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why still use iframe?

Comment: Because there is a many images that i want to display it in this iframe, and leave the main page slight.

Comment: you don't have to use iframe for that, in fact, you should never use iframe (http://blondish.net/iframes-why-not-to-use-them/).

Comment: why `onclick` ? you could bind a `click` event using jQuery instead and fire fancybox from there BUT if you really, really, really want to use `onclick` then build a function that fires fancybox and call it from within the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I have found the solution by thi command:

Comment: <div class="addelement"><li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="addelements.php?value='+data.msg+'"></a></li></div> and i have made some modification in my js script to get directly the value for my showelementbox: $(window).load(function() {showelementbox("<?=$_GET['value'];?>"); });